# :invalid_mfa when calling Supervisor.start_child

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to start a child process in Elixir, and am receiving the following error:

```
{:error, {:invalid_mfa, {Worker, :start_link, "MY_TEAM_ID"}}}
```

My supervisor code looks something like this:

```
DynamicSupervisor.start_child(Worker.Supervisor, {Worker, "MY_TEAM_ID"})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message, the child_spec is supposed to pass its arguments as a list. Instead it should be `{:error, {:invalid_mfa, {Worker, :start_link, ["MY_TEAM_ID"]}}}` (note the [] around the params)

Inside your `Worker` module, check your `child_spec` function. It should look something like this (again, note the [] around team_id):

```
def child_spec(team_id) do
    %{
      id: __MODULE__,
      start: {__MODULE__, :start_link, [team_id]},
      type: :worker
    }
end
```

Comment: This issue has almost nothing to do with processes / supervisors / children, it’s a common format for [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3).